# Unit Method for User getUser() - Returns User object

Tags: apex, visualforce, community

[image]

Hi Everyone,

Above controller class will just return user info object, which is used for displaying user info in VF page. I am not sure how to cover the getUser() method in code coverage. here is my test method:

```
@IsTest 
public with sharing class testgetUserInfo{

  @isTest
    private static void testgetUser()
    {  
             User u = [SELECT Id,username FROM User WHERE id = :UserInfo.getUserId()]; 
            System.assertEquals(u.Username, UserInfo.getUserName());

        }


    @isTest
    private static void testClass()
    {
    getUserInfo controller = new getUserInfo() ;
        System.assertEquals([SELECT id, email, username, usertype, communitynickname, timezonesidkey, languagelocalekey, firstname, lastname, phone, title,
                street, city, country, postalcode, state, localesidkey, mobilephone, extension, fax, contact.email 
                FROM User
                WHERE id = :UserInfo.getUserId()].id,UserInfo.getUserId()); 
        System.AssertEquals(1,1);
}
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in your test class simply call the method.

```
@isTest
private static void testClass()
{

   private static test method void exampleTest(){
     getUserInfo controller = new getUserInfo() ;
     system.assertnotEquals(null,controller.getUser());
     system.assertEquals(userInfo.getUserID(), controller.getUser().id);

   }


}
```

Comment: As the class is called `getUserInfo` then `getUserInfo` is a constructor not a method. (Yes not an ideal naming pattern.)

Comment: @KeithC - Good catch, did not see that, answer edited....Still simple as calling the method which was not done in the OP test class.

Answer (score -2):

You getUsert() always return null, because in you code you aren not assign value to user attribute.

**Test Method**

```
@isTest
private static void testGetUser(){
    getUserInfo controller = new getUserInfo();

    System.assert(controller.getUser() == null);
}
```

Regards.